# How to print Facebook friends list

Tags: facebook

I need to print out my friends list on Facebook. However their instructions just bring me to a blank page. Something is wrong on my account since this happens on whatever PC, laptop I use. Is there a way I can print it off without using Facebook's instructions of entering settings and download a copy?  Also perhaps is there a way to print off my contacts from Messenger?  This would take the place of printing my friends list on Facebook. Facebook has ignored my support help request since Dec 7.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to print friend list is to [download a copy of your data](https://www.facebook.com/help/302796099745838) and look for [Friends](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/405183566203254) into data and print the list.

Other way is using [Facebook developer tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). See the [graph API overview](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/friend-list/#Overview) of friend list. A user [access token](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/) with `read_custom_friendlists` permission is required. Learn here => [how to use graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/).

Another way is to create a new Yahoo! email account and import your Facebook contacts with Yahoo! contacts. Then print from Yahoo! contacts, it will include person name and email id.

Answer (score -3):

I think what you are looking for is : 
[Friends Manager CRM](https://apps.facebook.com/283318771779450/)

Try that, if it works well for you.
Good Luck.

Comment: First line of that link is '**Friends Manager CRM doesn't synchronize with your Facebook friends anymore**'.